# CSS selector after element and before element

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is the way to divide P tags after H2 and  after H3 in following structure. The Paragraphs after h2  need other style.

```
H2
P
P
H3
P
P
P
H2
P
P
...
H3
P
P
```

Comment: Use the `+` combinator: `h2 + p` means paragraph after `h2`, and so on.

Comment: Do you have control over the markup? If so then I'd definitely consider wrapping the p tags in a div or span with a class that describes the grouping.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I cant control html markup

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

**h2 > p** (CSS 2):
Selects all **p** elements where the parent is a **h2** element

**h2 + p** (CSS 2):
Selects all **p** elements that are placed immediately after **h2** elements

**h2 ~ p** (CSS 3):
Selects every **p** element that are preceded by a **h2** element

Maybe this link can be useful:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

For your case:

```css
    h2 ~ p{
      font-size: 14px;
      color: red;
    }

    h3 + p, 
    h3 + p + p, 
    h3 + p + p + p{
      font-size: 12px;
      color: blue;
    }
```

```html
    <H2> H2 TAG </H2>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
    <H3> H3 TAG </H3>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
    <H2> H2 TAG </H2>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
    <H3> H3 TAG </H3>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
```

Comment: I know these selectors. I have no ideas how i can solve my issue using them. I have not any wrappers, all element are siblings

Comment: @TheBububo take a look again, I put example to you